# the problem with the installation Mattermost server

Tags: server, installation, mattermost

everyone.

OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7
install mattermost v. 5.11.0 instructions https://docs.mattermost.com/install/install-rhel-7.html#installing-postgresql-database
postgresql V. 9.4 on the same server.

file /opt/mattermost/config/config.json

```
"DriverName": "postgres",
"DataSource": "postgres://mmuser:12345678@localhost:5432/mattermost?sslmode=disable&connect_timeout=10",
```

file /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE DATABASE USER ADDRESS METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local all all trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host all all 127.0.0.1/32 ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host all all ::1/128 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local replication postgres peer
#host replication postgres 127.0.0.1/32 ident
#host replication postgres ::1/128 ident
```

during the installation phase of the mattermost server, when you run step 8 "Test the Mattermost server to make sure everything works." after command: sudo -u mattermost ./bin/mattermost
getting an error:

```
[root@srv-testserver mattermost]# sudo -u mattermost ./bin/mattermost
{"level":"info","ts":1558609830.586414,"caller":"utils/i18n.go:83","msg":"Loaded system translations for 'en' from '/opt/mattermost/i18n/en.json'"}
{"level":"info","ts":1558609830.5868208,"caller":"app/server_app_adapters.go:58","msg":"Server is initializing..."}
{"level":"info","ts":1558609830.5903602,"caller":"sqlstore/supplier.go:224","msg":"Pinging SQL master database"}
{"level":"error","ts":1558609830.6013992,"caller":"sqlstore/supplier.go:236","msg":"Failed to ping DB retrying in 10 seconds err=pq: Ident authentication failed for user \"mmuser\""}
```

please help advice

Comment: What have you tried for resolving this? What have you tried for debugging?

Comment: Solved it.
set /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_hba.conf


    # TYPE DATABASE USER ADDRESS METHOD
    # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
    #local all all trust
    # IPv4 local connections:
    host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust
    # IPv6 local connections:
    host all all ::1/128 ident
    # Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
    # replication privilege.
    #local replication postgres peer
    #host replication postgres 127.0.0.1/32 ident
    #host replication postgres ::1/128 ident